# How can I stop the date format changing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I am using a simple form to enter dates in certain cells (Start_date and End_Date). The date format in the form is set to dd/mm/yyyy which works fine. However, when the VBA code copies it to the sheet it swaps it round to mm/dd/yyyy.
If I enter 01/02/2022 as a Start_Date it swaps to 02/01/2022.
If I enter 15/02/2022 as an End_Date it stays as 15/02/2022 (any day date 13 and above is OK)

```
Sheet5.Range("D1").Value = TaskFrm.Start_Date.Value 'Start Date
Sheet5.Range("E1").Value = TaskFrm.End_Date.Value 'End date
```

I am not sure how to get round this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Excel will parse dates according to your Windows Regional Short Date format. The format that you set in Excel only controls how the dates are **displayed**.  My suggestions: 1) Use a calendar control to enter the dates; 2) enter the D, M and Y in separate boxes; 3) if you must enter as a string, parse the string in VBA and construct the date from the parts.  Choice 3 is the most error-prone (users can enter dates incorrectly - eg as MDY when they mean DMY) but doable.

Comment: You can add the date format in code directly?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Windows is set to UK for date format. I will try with a calendar control, sounds the best way.